# И снова обороты с союзом "как"

Tags: пунктуация

Как быть с запятыми перед союзом "как" в этих двух случаях?

...кто имеет право выполнять перевод, кому принадлежат права на него, как на результат интеллектуальной деятельности группы лиц.

В производство запущены полнопроходные краны DN 50, 80 и 100 мм со строительной длиной, как у задвижки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В первом случае запятая не нужна ("как" в значении "в качестве"), а во втором предложении запятая перед "как" нужна (здесь сравнение)

Comment: Спасибо большое. Никак не могу с ними разобраться...

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что во втором предложении запятая не нужна: "В производство запущены полнопроходные краны DN 50, 80 и 100 мм со строительной длиной как у задвижки".

Смысл такой: "Со строительной длиной как у задвижки" - это "со строительной длиной, равной длине задвижки". А при обособлении получается, что краны, как и задвижки, обладают строительной длиной.

Это следует из похожих текстов в Интернете: "В производство запущены полнопроходные краны DN 50, 80 и 100 мм со строительной длиной, как у задвижки.Из разговоров с конечными потребителями стало понятно, что есть потребность именно в полнопроходных кранах, имеющих строительную длину, равную длине задвижки, для снижения затрат по модернизации имеющихся трубопроводов".

Comment: В таком случае здесь неправильно построено предложение. Так и надо было бы написать: "В производство запущены полнопроходные краны DN 50, 80 и 100 мм со строительной длиной, равной длине задвижки".

Comment: Да, так и надо  было бы написать. А сейчас смысл вроде бы ясен, а формальная грамматика не передает его правильно.

Answer (score 0):

В первом случае - нет
Во втором предложении так называемого сравнения нет.  Здесь подразумевается : те же, что и у ... ; равной длине задвижки

Answer (score 0):

Во втором случае запятая нужна, т.к. здесь отождествление, приравнивание.

Comment: Серж, мы не отождествляем вентиль с заглушкой, а говорим о равенстве/тождестве их строительных длин. При обособлении предложение надо перестроить: В производство запущены полнопроходные краны DN 50, 80 и 100 мм с такой строительной длиной, как у задвижки. Это отсутствующее местоимение "такой" и создает проблемы. Сравните: Все как всегда. Все  так, как всегда.Тропинка извивается как змея Тропинка извивается так,  как змея.

Comment: Вера, в том и дело, что мы приравниваем не краны, а длину. Здесь "как" относится именно к длине, а не к вентилям.

Comment: Мы догадываемся, что относится к длине, но грамматически получается, что к вентилям. Вот, например, вы говорите продавцу: Подберите мне лыжи с длиной как на образце (указываете отличительный признак). Вы же не будете здесь обособлять оборот?

Comment: Это можно трактовать как выражение длины в натуральных единицах измерения.

У него длина хвоста 2м. 

У него длина хвоста как у крокодила. 

Формально:

Длина хвоста ..........  2м (как 2 эталона метра, хранящихся в...)

Длина хвоста ..........  как у крокодила (подставить среднестатистическую длину ХК)